# Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected from a file. Try Console.Read

Tags: c#, streamreader

Cannot get program to read the file, not sure what I'm doing wrong here, any advice is welcomed. 
Trying to do a project for an address book and the file contains all the people's names and addresses and phone numbers.

```
 public Form1()
        {
            string filename = "Addresses.txt";
            ReadFile(filename);
            ReadTokens(filename);
        }//end of main

        static void ReadFile(string filename)
        {
            StreamReader readFile;
            readFile = File.OpenText(filename);
            while (!readFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(readFile.ReadLine());
            }//end of while
            {
                readFile.Close();
                Console.ReadKey();
            }//End of read file
        }
        static void ReadTokens(string filename)
        {
            StreamReader readFile;
            string line;
            char[] delim = { ',' };
            readFile = File.OpenText(filename);
            while (!readFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                line = readFile.ReadLine(); // reads one line at a time
                string[] tokens = line.Split(delim);
                foreach (string str in tokens)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(str + "\t\t");
                }//end of for each
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
            readFile.Close();
        }//end of ReadTokens
    }//end of program
}//end namespace
```

Comment: Is that a Windows Forms app? They don't have consoles, so `Console.ReadKey` does nothing. Also, you probably don't want much business logic in the form constructor; it should go in a handler for the form's `Load` or `Shown` event.

Comment: I have this issue when executing the application from MINGW